# Servlet and mapping name

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

Hello I am a newbie and I am new at JEE.
I try to connect my servlet class to the `web.xml` file but I always have this error:

> Servlet should have a mapping name

and I don't know why and what is the purpose of adding a mapping name
Here is my `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SelectLiquorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sample.SelectLiquorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First : Servlet mapping specifies the web container of which java servlet should be invoked for a url given by client. It maps url patterns to servlets. When there is a [request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message) from a client, [servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) decides to which application it should forward to. Then context path of url is matched for mapping servlets.

See first bullet of step # 2 on Wikipedia page, [*Java Servlet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet). (Emphasis added)

> The following is a typical user scenario of these methods.
>
> 1. Assume that a user requests to visit a URL.
>
>    - The browser then generates an HTTP request for this URL.
>        This request is then sent to the appropriate server.
> 2. The HTTP request is received by the web server and forwarded to the servlet container.
>
>    - The **container maps this request to a particular servlet**. ⬅
>    - The servlet is dynamically retrieved and loaded into the address space of the container.
> 3. The container invokes the init() method of the servlet.
>      …

To solve your problem you need to add the following lines:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SelectLiquorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SelectLiquor</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Happy Coding